# Nested JSON array object code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have json object in data after ajax call like

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$id": "58d8e2831d7859e80d000033"
    },
    "broadcast_id": 70,
    "studentList": "",
    "employeeList": "999",
    "mailTitle": "adsf",
    "broadcastMessage": "dsfsdf dsd fgd",
    "emailSent": "0",
    "userdetails": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$id": "58d8eaba1d7859c81300002e"
    },
    "broadcast_id": 72,
    "studentList": "",
    "employeeList": "999|788",
    "mailTitle": "Hekjh",
    "broadcastMessage": "hhyky jk",
    "emailSent": "0",
    "userdetails": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$id": "58dde8ed1d78597011000029"
    },
    "user_id": 1,
    "broadcast_id": 76,
    "studentList": "",
    "employeeList": "999|788",
    "mailTitle": "Hello",
    "broadcastMessage": "How are u ",
    "emailSent": "0",
    "dateSent": "31/03/2017",
    "userdetails": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$id": "568f95dc99fbadb016000029"
        },
        "uid": 1,
        "username": "test",
        "password": "LeLafe#7861",
        "email_id": "sales@lelafe.com",
        "creation_date": "",
        "role": "admin",
        "is_enabled": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I am trying parse nested json attribute **userdetails** in order to role and display it in a table. I have tried following lines

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'index.php?action=fetchBroadcastedMessageList',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         data: { usertype: usertype },
         success: function(data) {
             for (var i in data) {
                 $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
                     '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
                     '' + data[i].userdetails["role"] + '' +
                     '</td>'...
                 );
             }
         });
 }
```

The line `data[i].userdetails["role"]` does not retrieve corresponding role
value whereever there are userdetails available. Please help me !!!

Comment: The userdetails is contains an array, you have to use data[i].userdetails[0]["role"] in order to do what you want to

Comment: data[i].userdetails is an array

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional level (`[0]`), since `userdetails` returns an array. For this to work you must first check if the array has elements:

```
   $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
      '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
          (data[i].userdetails.length ? data[i].userdetails[0]["role"] : '') +
      '</td>'
   );
```

Maybe you want the check on the array length to happen earlier, so that you can omit the `append` completely when the array has no elements. Depends on what you expect...

```
if (data[i].userdetails.length) {
   $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
      '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
          data[i].userdetails[0]["role"] +
      '</td>'
   );
}
```

Comment: Solution looks good but what if userdetails is a string, it will also have a length property. In that case userdetails[0] can give awkward results

Comment: Sure, it would also give awkward results if it was a date, a boolean, null, ... But OP's sample data suggests that it always is an array. I assume of course there is a consistent structure in the received JSON.

Comment: This can be done just to be sure "Array.isArray(userdetails)" before checking the length property.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like this

```
 $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?action=fetchBroadcastedMessageList',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {usertype: usertype},
       success: function (data) {
            $.each(data , function(key,value)) {
                       $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
                              '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
                              '' + value.userdetails[0]["role"] + '' +
                              '</td>'...
           );
           }
       });  
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

rather use forEach and then just use that object. It seems that is what you are trying to achieve anyway.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=fetchBroadcastedMessageList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {usertype: usertype},
                    success: function (data) {
                 data.forEach(function(obj) {
                  $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
                   '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
                   '' + obj.userdetails.role + '' +
                   '</td>'...
           );
       });
       });  
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is the case if userdetails is not an array, I am not sure why you want to make it an array? Otherwise trincot has a nice answer

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
data.userdetails[0].role
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data= [{"_id":{"$id":"58d8e2831d7859e80d000033"},"broadcast_id":70,"studentList":"","employeeList":"999","mailTitle":"adsf","broadcastMessage":"dsfsdf dsd fgd","emailSent":"0",
            "userdetails":[]},
     {"_id":{"$id":"58d8eaba1d7859c81300002e"},"broadcast_id":72,"studentList":"","employeeList":"999|788","mailTitle":"Hekjh","broadcastMessage":"hhyky jk","emailSent":"0",
          "userdetails":[]},
     {"_id":{"$id":"58dde8ed1d78597011000029"},"user_id":1,"broadcast_id":76,"studentList":"","employeeList":"999|788","mailTitle":"Hello","broadcastMessage":"How are u ","emailSent":"0","dateSent":"31\/03\/2017",
           "userdetails":[{"_id":{"$id":"568f95dc99fbadb016000029"},"uid":1,"username":"test","password":"LeLafe#7861","email_id":"sales@lelafe.com","creation_date":"",
           "role":"admin",
           "is_enabled":1}]}]
           
           $.each(data,function(i,item){
           if(item.userdetails.length > 0)
           {
           $.each(item.userdetails,function(i,userdetail){
           $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +'<td style="text-align: center;">' +userdetail.role +'</td>');
           });
           }
           else
           {
           $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +'<td style="text-align: center;">' +'not available' +'</td>');
           }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="broadcastedmessagelist">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you need an extra level nesting. Also suggest using the es6 template strings for a cleaner string interpolation.

```
data.map((i)=>{
  if(i.userdetails.length >0){
    $("#broadcastedmessagelist")
    .append(`<tr><td style="text-align:center;">${i.userdetails[0].role}</td>`);
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** **`userdetails`** is an array so to access any element from an array you have to use like this **:** `data[i].userdetails[0]["role"]`

**try this :**

```
for (var i in data) {
                 $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
                     '<td style="text-align: center;">' +
                     '' + data[i].userdetails[0]["role"] + '' +
                     '</td>'...
                 );
             }
```

Answer (score -1):

/* below code will call to index.php, catch the json response and render HTML  */

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?action=fetchBroadcastedMessageList',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {usertype: usertype},
  success: function (data) {
 $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr><td>broadcastMessage</td><td>broadcast_id</td><td>emailSent</td><td>employeeList</td><td>mailTitle</td><td>studentList</td><td>userdetails</td></tr>');
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
      var stringBuilder = '<tr><td>' + value.broadcastMessage + '</td><td>' + value.broadcast_id + '</td><td>' + value.emailSent + '</td><td>' + value.employeeList + '</td><td>' + value.mailTitle + '</td><td>' + value.studentList + '</td>';

      if(value.userdetails.length > 0){
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder + '<td><table border="1"><tr><td>uid</td><td>username</td><td>password</td><td>email_id</td><td>creation_date</td><td>is_enabled</td><td>role</td></tr>';
        $.each(value.userdetails, function(k,v){
          stringBuilder =  stringBuilder + '<tr><td>' + v.uid + '</td><td>' + v.username + '</td><td>' + v.password + '</td><td>' + v.email_id + '</td><td>' + v.creation_date + '</td><td>' + v.is_enabled + '</td><td>' + v.role + '</td></tr>';
        });
        stringBuilder =  stringBuilder + '</table></td>';
      }else{
        stringBuilder =  stringBuilder + '<td></td>';
      }
      stringBuilder =  stringBuilder + '</tr>';
      $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append(stringBuilder);
    });
     }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged at SO. Please, explain in words, what was wrong and how you suggest to fix that.